# Best settings for xml sitemap, cron time and submission time?

Tags: cron, xml-sitemap

i have news site for about 7 months.

The site get new feeds every hour but google take about 1 day to index them and only few of them.

I see other sites that instantly index. "1 hours ago etc". Mine newest in google says "19 hours ago"+. And after some errors with sitemap, now i have 0 links last 2-3 days.

So, i wan't to share my configs and you tell me if something is wrong:

1. Feeds module import feeds every hour
2. cron runs every 3 hours
3. xmlsitemap sumbission time to search engines is every 3 hour

`I want to notice that i have arround 130.000 links. I have many feeds who import content. Maby are too much to index? idk`

So, what im doing wrong?
PS: Also, every time i submit xml sitemap, i must ping google? if yes, i ping home page or xmlsitemap?

Comment: It's probably because Google doesn't consider your site worthy of being updated every hour. You need to get more traffic and rank higher in order to get that.

Comment: a! so its because of google and i can't do anything. nc!

Answer (score 1):

The indexing you are having is moderate / typical indeed. Only a small percentage of sites (from the 100% existing in the web right now) are being indexed every hour or so (some sites are indexed once smaller times like 20 minutes or even less - Wikipedia for example could be indexed in 10 minutes or less in some cases).

You should use various Drupal modules to raise the both PageRank and PQS (Page quality score) of your sites pages.

Use wisely the modules [MetaTag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag), [AdvAgg](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg), [xml sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap), [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto), [search404](https://www.drupal.org/project/search404), [redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) and others to insure you achieve that targets.

More ways to handle that many 404's - Either your could redirect all the nodes to the homepage or groups of them to some nodes with suitable context).  Moreover, if you have the spare timenergy or resources you could make redirects to NID's 1x1 for all or most of your links. You could also delete some via WMT and than via robots.txt. It is recommended by some to make redirects not in Drupal but rather directly in the main .htaccess file for better performance.

Comment: Hey, i have the first 5 modules. My SEO is fine... the only question i have is about 404. As i said the site gets content from feeds and every day i can get more than 1000 feed items. That means that after some time some links are broken or whatever. I have about 900 404 links in GWT. THERE IS NO CONTENT to redirect. What i can do in this case? can i 301 to home page? bcause google "punish" sites with many 404 errors :(

Comment: I've expanded my answer a bit; These directions might be good especially if you have the help of some modules or scripts.

Comment: Deleting links via WMT idk if is good idea. Because ALWAYS it will be new broken links and are too many to do it manually :( that happens when you automatically grab RSS from 50 sites. I think i will redirect all links to home page.

Answer (score 0):

If the site is largely linking back out to other sites, you may be appearing to be a link-farm and Google isn't going to re-index frequently.

If you have good reasons to be pulling lots of feeds with broken links in them I recommend adding a process that checks the new links before making them public. It'll make your users happier as well as Google.